# What This "E" Part Is Doing in CBC mode?

Tags: java, cryptography, cbc-mode

[image: I did not understand E box]

I need to implement this mode in java by hand ( DES )
What is going in that E (encryption) box?

Comment: Whatever Encryption algorithm : AES, DES, RSA, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function E is *the block cipher* DES:

- with as input the key K - 64 bits of which 56 are actually used (the arrow at the left of E) and
- as second input a plaintext block of 64 bits of data, as the block size is 64 bits (the arrow at the top of E)
- as output again a 64 bit block of ciphertext (the arrow at the bottom of E)

Now note that the input plaintext block for the *block cipher* E differs from the input blocks of the DES-CBC. You should see this as a function DES-CBC that uses multiple calls to the function DES *internally*.

If you don't have any implementation of the block cipher DES then you can use DES-ECB and call it with one block / 8 bytes of (unpadded) data at a time.

And if that's not available you can use a single block encrypt in CBC or CTR mode with an IV consisting of 8 zero bytes, as that comes down to the same thing (XOR of a block of data with a block of all zero bytes just gives you the same block of data again, after all).